# Error on an SQL trigger between 2 tables, one of which has a foreign key on the other

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Hello I am having the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281819/postgresql-delete-trigger) problem with a trigger, I do not understand my error.
The script compiles but when I delete an element I have this error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_foreign_key() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $_$

  BEGIN 
       
          delete from planning.ordrelivraison_history 
          where ordrelivraison_history.ordrelivraisonid = old.planning.ordrelivraison.ordreid;
      RETURN OLD;
   END;


$_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


Create trigger delete_foreign_key_in_order_delivery_history
  after delete 
     on planning.ordrelivraison_history 
    for each row
execute procedure delete_foreign_key();

------------------------------------------------------

delete
from planning.ordrelivraison

where ordreid = 1656
```

---

Voici l'erreur

ERROR: ERROR: UPDATE or DELETE on the "delivery order" table violates the foreign key constraint
"Ordrelivraison_history_ordreid" from the "ordrelivraison_history" table
DETAIL: The key (orderid) = (1656) is always referenced from the “ordrelivraison_history” table.

SQL state: 23503

Comment: What is the error  you get?  One obvious error is that you forgot the "closing" `$_$` for the function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trouble in you are firing the trigger at the wrong time. You declare it as `AFTER delete` but that makes it an  *after statement* trigger, unfortunately the trigger function does not get the old/new rows on  after statement trigger. See [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtrigger.html) documentation. Change your trigger to:

```
Create trigger delete_foreign_key_in_order_delivery_history
   after delete 
      on ordrelivraison_history 
     for each row
 execute procedure delete_foreign_key();
```